# Create role programmatically with parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm looking for a way to create a function that takes in two parameters for user name and password and creates a read only role with it. I've tried something like:

```
create or replace function create_user_readonly (
  unm varchar,
  pwd varchar
)
  returns varchar(10) as $$

begin

  create role unm login password @pwd;
  return 'success';

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

This throws the error:

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "@" Position: 151

I thought of using dynamic SQL to construct the query but ran into this here (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html):

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in 
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands. In other statement types 
>   (generically called utility statements), you must insert values textually 
>   even if they are just data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example:

```
create or replace function create_user_readonly (
  unm varchar,
  pwd varchar
)
  returns varchar(10) as $$

begin

  execute format($f$create role %I login password '%s'$f$,unm,pwd);
  execute format('alter role %I set transaction_read_only to on',unm);
  return 'success';

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

keep in mind though you will need to alter user to set `transaction_read_only` also to make it read only.
**also**:

`CREATE ROLE` [does not offer setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) RO default to role.

`ALTER ROLE` [does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html)

And keep in mind that overcoming uset configuration `transaction_read_only` is as easy as running one statement.

and create role won't give `CONNECT` permission, use `CREATE USER` instead if you want one.

Comment: Thanks Vao, that totally worked! Your name should be Wow :) Is the ```transaction_read_only``` not something that can be done in the same statement as ```create role```?

Comment: not really, at least I never tried and it is not documented :)

Comment: updated with your note and added several mine as nota bene

Comment: Thanks mucho! I appreciate the nota benes :)